# LinqDataSource - filtering for null values

Tags: asp.net, null, filter, linqdatasource

I am writing an ASP.Net web application.  I have listview, it's datasource is a LinqDataSource.  In my database, I have a staff table and I am trying filter for records by their team using a dropdownlist.  This works fine, until I select "All" in the dropdownlist.  It returns all staff except for the ones where the teamID is null.  How can I return the records where teamID is null?

This is my code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsStaff" DataKeyNames="staffID">

    <LayoutTemplate>
<table>
  <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Team</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp</td>
     <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTeamFilter" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsTeams" DataTextField="Team" DataValueField="TeamID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="[All]" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tr>
</table>
</LayoutTemplate>
....
</asp:Listview>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsStaff" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="ProjectDatabase.ProjectDatabaseUsersDataContext" OrderBy="name" 
    TableName="Staffs" EnableUpdate="True" Where="inService == @inService &amp;&amp; TeamID == @TeamID">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="true" Name="inService" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ListView1$ddlTeamFilter" Name="TeamID" Type="Int32" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
     </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

In my code behind I handle the LinqDataSource selecting event:

```
Private Sub ldsStaff_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles ldsStaff.Selecting
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(ListView1.FindControlRecursive("ddlTeamFilter"), DropDownList)
    If ddl.SelectedValue = "" Then
        e.WhereParameters.Remove("TeamID")
    End If
```

I thought that if I removed the whereparameter when the dropdownlist is "All" it would force it to return all the records, but it doesn't work.

Please help!

Thanks,
Emma

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the selecting event anyway I would remove the Where clause in your datasource all together and handle everything in the selecting event setting the e.Result value to your linq query.

Then in your `ddlTeamFilter` rebind the listview on change.

Hope this helps.